# Hartl rails tutorial -- current_user.microposts.build

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Not exactly sure how to frame this question. I'm confused as to how `current_user.microposts.build` works, as shown here:

```
class MicropostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]
  def create
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(micropost_params)
    if @micropost.save
      flash[:success] = "Micropost created!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'static_pages/home'
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

I understand that current_user was defined earlier in the sessions helper, but where does `microposts` come from? I believe we're accessing the microposts model which is linked to a user with `belongs_to`, but the model itself is called Micropost -- so how does rails know that Micropost = microposts? In addition, when we use `belongs_to`, why do we do `belongs_to :user` instead of `belongs_to user`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% familiar with the tutorial but think that I can answer all of your questions.

> where does microposts come from?

On the `User` model, you likely have a line like this:

```
has_many :microposts
```

When you define an association like that, you can call it as a method on any objects instantiated from your `User` class.

> I believe we're accessing the microposts model which is linked to a user with belongs_to, but the model itself is called Micropost -- so how does rails know that Micropost = microposts?

The convention is to define a `has_many` relationship using a plural name, denoting that the association represents a collection of records.

By convention, Rails uses [inflections](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html) to automatically translate words [from singular to plural](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-pluralize) (and [vice versa](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-singularize)) in order to determine which model class and database table to look up. This is the convention/default, but you could override this if you really wanted to, though I would advise against that in 95% of cases.

```
has_many :microposts, class_name: 'BlogPost'
```

> In addition, when we use `belongs_to`, why do we do `belongs_to :user` instead of `belongs_to user`?

`belongs_to user` would cause an error because you're saying, "Call the `belongs_to` initializer and pass as the first argument the value stored in the variable `user`." I'm guessing in your example that the variable `user` wouldn't be defined.

`belongs_to :user` is passing a symbol, which is *sort of* like a string (i.e., `belongs_to 'user'`). With the symbol, you're instructing `belongs_to` to initialize an association named `user`. Based on that symbol, Rails deduces which database table, model class, etc. you're referencing unless you tell it to do otherwise with options like the `class_name` that I used in an earlier example.

Answer (score 0):

Rails knows to link the model `Micropost` to the table `microposts`  using a convention: `[model] + s = table` (there're also more complex pluralization rules). This principle is called CoC (Convention over Configuration). It's a major part of rails' philosophy.

[Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration):

> Convention over configuration (also known as coding by convention) is a software design paradigm used by software frameworks that attempt to decrease the number of decisions that a developer using the framework is required to make without necessarily losing flexibility. The concept was introduced by David Heinemeier Hansson to describe the philosophy of the Ruby on Rails web framework, but is related to earlier ideas like the concept of "sensible defaults" and the principle of least astonishment in user interface design